# Como deixar imagem responsiva

Tags: css

Estou trabalhando em um site com característica responsiva e nele tenho uma página de promoções e gostaria que as imagens acompanhassem a mudança de tamanho do navegador, o tamanho máximo da largura da imagem é 1080px, seguindo algumas dicas de companheiros refiz o css e exemplo exibido isoladamente funciona corretamente, mas ao inseri-lo em minhas Tabs o mesmo não funciona, ficou assim:

```
div#page {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

O código para exibição:

```
<div id="page"> 
<img src="minhaimagem.png" alt="">
```

A página pode ser vista aqui:

[Página de Promoções:](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/promocoes)

O código da minha TAB está assim:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Tabs
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.ui-tabs {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5em; /* 18px */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    width:1100px;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-helper-reset {
    line-height: 1.5em; /* 18px */
}

.ui-tabs .ui-widget-content {
    color: #383838;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000em;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-widget-header,
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active {
    background: none;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px -1px 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border: none;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #383838;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active a {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 6px; /* makes the unselected tabs appear above the border */
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-disabled a {
    color: #888 !important;
    cursor: default;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Vejam no tamanho da TAB coloquei esse valor para que ela possa ficar expandida:

```
width:1100px;
```

Ainda não consegui deixar a imagem responsiva dentro das TAB´s mesmo seguindo a dica de deixar a div pai com percentagem.

Comment: Você usa Bootstrap ou coisa parecida champs?

Comment: Olá @Edgar Muniz Berlinck, não uso bootstrap.

Comment: amigo, você gostaria de ter algo semelhante ao encontrado nesta pagina? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Comment: Aqui funcionou. Talvez você esqueceu de finalizar a `div.responsivo`? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sn5axcp/)

Comment: Olá @ JSFiddle, sim a div está fechada.

Comment: @Oeslei, mas o comportamento da imagem em resoluções maiores que 1080px é estranho, tente ver o seu JSFindle em tela cheia: http://jsfiddle.net/5sn5axcp/embedded/result/

Comment: @TobyMosque Por que estranho? Está fazendo exatamente o esperado.

Comment: @adventistapr Meu nome não é JSFiddle =) É apenas um link para você conferir um exemplo funcionando.

Comment: Olá @Oeslei, me perdoe a confusão, acho que copiei e colei sem perceber.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151114/imagem-responsiva/235759#235759

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Se pôr a imagem com largura de 100% ela se ajustará ao tamanho do container onde ela se encontra. Caso não esteja dentro de nenhum container se ajustará ao tamanho da página.

```html
Dentro de container, container de tamanho 30% da largura total:
<div style="width:30%">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q579U.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

Solta na página, pega a largura total da janela.
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q579U.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder @Antonio Alexandre, ajudou muito.

Comment: Que bom adventista! Fico feliz em saber! Grande abraço! :-)

Comment: Na real, a resposta para sua pergunta é uso de Media Queries...

Answer (score 18):

experimente utilizar o background-size como no exemplo abaixo e verifique se no head do site está definido a meta tag: viewport

```
.responsivo {
           max-width: 1080px;
           width: 100%;
           height: auto;
  }
  .responsivo img{
          max-width: 1080px;   /* Máximo da largura da imagem */
          width: 100%;
          max-height: 500px;  /* Máximo da altura da imagem */
          min-height: auto;      /* Mínimo da altura, por padrão “auto” */
          background-size:100%;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Comment: Olá @Miguel Batista, obrigado pela dica, o head do site não está definindo a tag, fiz um teste com o código passado e nada foi alterado.

Comment: Olá cara, fiz um exemplo no link http://jsfiddle.net/dte64k0v/ experimente dar um resize no bloco da imagem. Vale ressaltar que a div pai deve utilizar width sempre em %;

Comment: Bacana! eu não sabia que o `background-size` funcionava na tag `img`

Comment: Tudo que precisa pra fazer isso é o `width: 100%`. Existe algum motivo para botar esses `background-xxx` aí?